# Parsing an XML file using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I am having two issues with parsing an XML file. I want to only return one set of properties I.E only the property values under the first Process and I want to return the second Source under the second Process. When I use my code it returns the Source under the first Sources and the first Source under the second Sources but I cannot get the second Source to return.

The XML file looks like:

```
<!-- The description of the process -->
<Description>"This is a description"</Description>

<!-- info on process to be run -->
<Process expectFailure="false">
    <Code>Import</Code>
    <Sources>
        <Source>"Test Data"</Source>
    </Sources>
    <Destination>Buffered</Destination>
    <Properties>
        <Property code="format" value="CC"/>
        <Property code="Input" value="10N"/>
        <Property code="Method" value="BASIC"/>
        <Ppoperty code="Resolution" value="5"/>
        <Property code="Convention" value="LEFT"/>
        <Property code="Bounding" value="BUFFERED"/>
    </Properties>
</Process>

<!-- info on second process to be run (compare) -->
<Process>
    <Code>SurfaceCompare</Code>
    <Sources>
        <Source>expectedOutput</Source>
        <Source>Buffered</Source>
    </Sources>
    <Properties>
        <Property code="compare_designated" value="true"/>
        <Property code="compare_metadata" value="true"/>
        <Property code="metadata_type" value="OTHER"/>
    </Properties>
</Process>
```

and the code looks like

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse("XML_example.xml")

description = tree.findtext("Description")
print(description)

for process in tree.findall('Process'):
    for source in process.findall('Sources'):
        source_text = source.findtext('Source')
        print(source_text)

#returns everything
for property in process.iter('Property'):
    print(property.attrib.get('code'))
    print(property.attrib.get('value'))

for process in tree.findall('Process'):
    for source in process.findall('Sources'):
        source = source.findtext('Source')
        print(source)
```

I've tried a lot of different ways of using the findall, find, iter, get, getiter methods. I am sure I am missing something but it has been a long day and for the life of me I can't see what I am missing.

There is also the ability to change how the XML is set up but I know there must be a way to solve this question and it is gnawing at me.

Sample proper output for sources:

```
"Test Data"
expectedOutput
buffered
```

Sample proper output 1 for properties:

```
format
CC
Input
10N
Method
BASIC
Convention
LEFT
Bounding
BUFFERED
```

Sample proper output 2:

```
compare_designated 
true
compare_metadata 
true
metadata_type 
OTHER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simplest way to achieve what you want is to use `find` or `findall` with the **path**, **iter** works well with **tag** name but in your case using **path** will be more suitable.

Here is one way of doing it, by the way, your sample is missing a **root** element thus I've added in my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from StringIO import StringIO

s = '''<!-- The description of the process -->
<Description>"This is a description"</Description>

<!-- info on process to be run -->
<Process expectFailure="false">
    <Code>Import</Code>
    <Sources>
        <Source>"Test Data"</Source>
    </Sources>
    <Destination>Buffered</Destination>
    <Properties>
        <Property code="format" value="CC"/>
        <Property code="Input" value="10N"/>
        <Property code="Method" value="BASIC"/>
        <Ppoperty code="Resolution" value="5"/>
        <Property code="Convention" value="LEFT"/>
        <Property code="Bounding" value="BUFFERED"/>
    </Properties>
</Process>

<!-- info on second process to be run (compare) -->
<Process>
    <Code>SurfaceCompare</Code>
    <Sources>
        <Source>expectedOutput</Source>
        <Source>Buffered</Source>
    </Sources>
    <Properties>
        <Property code="compare_designated" value="true"/>
        <Property code="compare_metadata" value="true"/>
        <Property code="metadata_type" value="OTHER"/>
    </Properties>
</Process>'''
```

---

```
# once you've parsed the file, you need to **getroot()**
tree = ET.parse(StringIO('<root>' + s + '</root>')).getroot()
```

For example, you can use path to get from first **Process[1] -> Properties -> Property**, using `findall` you can get to all **Property** nodes, and iterate them:

```
# and iterate all Property nodes, and get their attributes like this
for p in tree.findall('./Process[1]/Properties/Property'):
    print p.attrib # to get code/value, use p.attrib.get('code') etc.
```

Thus you get the first **Process/Properties** and all **Property**'s attributes:

```
{'code': 'format', 'value': 'CC'}
{'code': 'Input', 'value': '10N'}
{'code': 'Method', 'value': 'BASIC'}
{'code': 'Convention', 'value': 'LEFT'}
{'code': 'Bounding', 'value': 'BUFFERED'}
```

Another example, to get just the second **Process**, second **Source** text, using **path** is quite straight forward with just `find`, too:

```
print tree.find('./Process[2]/Sources/Source[2]').text
Buffered
```

I hope you get the idea of how to use them, remember to get a single node you use `find`, to return a list of nodes, you use `findall`, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you I don't have time to try it now but it looks promising. Will try when I get home.

Comment: @erics12512354, no worries take your time and I'm sure once you get the idea of how the **path** works you'll have problem solving the issue :)

Comment: It works. I didn't realize you could add positional arguments to the file paths and I was missing the ./ and when I tried that. Thanks again.

Comment: @erics12512354, glad it helps. Yes it's a little similar to xpath :)